# How do I jump out of enclosing parentheses?

Tags: evil, spacemacs, smartparens

I'm using `spacemacs` to edit Python code.

When I type an opening parentheses, the closing parentheses is automatically inserted for me and the cursor is put in the middle for further typing.  But: once I am done typing inside the parentheses, I need a quick way of jumping  out of them and landing after the closing parenthesis.

Right now, I switch to  normal state, move the cursor one unit (when I'm on the character just before the closing parenthesis), and then re-enter insert state with `a`.  How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: (Don't use smartparens etc. in the first place?  IOW, if it hurts, don't do it. Why limit yourself to "*typing stuff inside the parentheses*"? Emacs already lets you know which right paren corresponds to which left paren. There is no need to hamstring yourself by creating little cells to work in.)

Comment: Can't you just type a closing paren? If not, try `C-M-n`.

Comment: @nanny Thanks. I was not aware of it.

Comment: @Drew You are right. But smartparens provides a couple of nice features too, especially useful for scheme/racket programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [`smartparens-mode`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens), the function `sp-up-sexp` will move you out of a set of parentheses (bind to your key of choice):

> Move forward out of one level of parentheses.
>
> ...
>
> Examples:
>
> `(foo |(bar baz) quux blab) -> (foo (bar baz) quux blab)|`
>
> `(foo (bar |baz) quux blab) -> (foo (bar baz) quux blab)| ;; 2`
>
> `(foo bar |baz              -> (foo bar baz)| ;; re-indent the expression
>   ​   )`
>
> `(foo  |(bar baz)           -> (foo)| (bar baz) ;; close unbalanced expr.`

To reiterate a simple version of the docstring examples, with the following text and `|` as the cursor:

```
(hey, I'm| in the parentheses) and I'm outside them
```

`M-x sp-up-sexp` (or whatever you bind that function to for convenience) will take you to:

```
(hey, I'm in the parentheses)| and I'm outside them
```

Also note that, if the cursor is *on* the closing parenthesis, you can just type that parenthesis and `smartparens` will interpret it to mean "move past this parenthesis" rather than "insert another parenthesis."

Answer (score 4):

Try `up-list` (which is a built-in Emacs function)

It lets me jump out of strings, parens, brackets with any nesting.